# SearchController - I dont want data to show when user has not started typing

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

]I have built a SearchViewController in my app, that simply searches for users.

Everything works great, except when i go into the viewcontroller it displays every user that is in the firebase database before i even have started searching? I want the tableview to not show results until i have typed at least 2 letters. Anyone know i can implement this?

Here is my code:

```
class FollowUsersTableViewController: UITableViewController ,UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate{

//    @IBOutlet var followUsersTableView: UITableView!

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
    filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
private var viewIsHiddenObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()
var loggedInUser: User?

var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //large title
    self.title = "Discover"
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    databaseRef.child("profile").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "uid")

        if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            self.usersArray.append(snapshot)
            //insert the rows
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } 
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filteredUsers.count
    }

    return self.usersArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FollowTableViewCell

    let user : NSDictionary?

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.title?.text = user?["username"] as? String
    let url = URL(string: user?["photoURL"] as! String)!
    cell.userImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_male"), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let arr = self.searchController.isActive ? self.filteredUsers : self.usersArray
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user", sender: arr[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let dest = segue.destination as! UserProfileViewController
    let obj = sender as![String:Any]
    dest.selectedUser = obj
}

func filterContent(searchText:String)
{
    if searchText != ""{
        self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in

            let username = user!["username"] as? String

            return(username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))! 
        }
    }
}
```

So does anyone have any tips on how i can make this work? 
[this is the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSm0a.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your numberOfRowsInSection you are returning self.usersArray.count.  If you don't to display all the results you can simply return 0 and none will appear.

If you want to display searches when at least 2 characters have been entered then use the count property of searchBar.text

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" && searchController.searchBar.text.count >= 2 {
        return filteredUsers.count
    }

    return 0

}
```

Comment: Hi, if i add return 0 (where i return self.usersArray.count) i get this error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: if you want to return no cells then return 0 is way to go.   Looks like you'll also need you check for character count in the cellForRow method.   your also inserting rows in viewDidLoad. Do you need to do this is you only want to display filtered ones?

Comment: Hello again, i havent added the character count yet, i only added the " return 0 " to numberOfRowsInSection as you stated above. But it gives me an error.. I only want to show filteredUsers, not usersArray, because i only want to show users when the user starts typing

Comment: i guess i need the usersArray to filter with the "filteredUsers" right?

Answer (score 0):

In your original code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filteredUsers.count
    }


    return self.usersArray.count

}
```

You're returning `self.userArray.count` so that probably explains why it shows the whole unfiltered array at the start without any text input into your searchbar.

I also noticed that your `filterContent(searchText:String)` function is not called in your code yet.

But I think the `return self.usersArray.count` line is okay as the default return value when you don't want to change the resulting table yet since it might look off to users when the table is empty, when there are 1 or 2 letters already typed in.

Also,

in the other part of your code:

`self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)`

I don't think `self.tableView.reloadData()` is necessary anymore when `insertRow` is used.

About your crash/error:

In your code block:

```
    if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            self.usersArray.append(snapshot)
            //insert the rows
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

instead of `self.tableView.reloadData()`

please try:

```
    if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            self.usersArray.append(snapshot)
            //insert the rows
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
```

This is to explicitly let the tableviewcontroller know that you're starting to edit/change the content. Please take note that using `beginUpdates()` is always paired with `endUpdates()`, and shouldn't be used along side `reloadData()`.

Comment: Yes, but i agree that i should return 0. But when i do, i get the error?

Comment: @MattGilbert A bit of an inference, but the `numberOfRowsInSection` function is a `UITableViewDataSource` function. And you're not really overriding anything since `FollowUsersTableViewController` is not a subclass of `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: So you will have to make `FollowUsersTableViewController` a subclass of `UITableViewDataSource` then assign self as the datasource of your table.

Comment: FollowUsersTableviewController class inherits from UITableViewController, and it should by default conforms to UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate. But still when i return 0 i get the error?

Comment: @MattGilbert You're right, my mistake! I'll look into it!

Comment: Thanks , really appreciate it! Im kinda stuck on this and i cant seem to find a solution, so it would be great if you could look into it :-)

Comment: @MattGilbert Is there an error message you can share?

Comment: @MattGilbert I think you should edit your question now to explain 2 problems. The first is your initial problem of only showing the filtered results, and the second is the crash.

Comment: @MattGilbert The crash/error you're getting is related to your `insertRow` call. That error means that your data source is not consistent with your current table view. Please try the code snippet I added in my answer!

Comment: i tried that now my friend, and i still get : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'